# How to SSH between Client and Host on Different Subnets, Same Network?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, subnet

On Home Network with two subnets:

- Client IP is 192.168.**1**.41 (Router subnet, netmask 255.255.255.0),
- SSHServer IP is 192.168.**0**.3 (Modem subnet, netmask 255.255.255.0).

If I try to SSH from Client to SSHServer, it times out. Yet, there is no problem if SSHServer is wirelessly connected to Router subnet (as 192.168.**1**.44, netmask 255.255.255.0) rather than wired to Modem subnet.

```
<ClientUSER>@Client:~$ ssh <ServerUSER>@192.168.0.3
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.3: Connection timed out
```

What is the simplest way to make this SSH connection from Client to SSHServer when they are on different subnets, respectively 192.168.**1**.* and 192.168.**0**.*?

Home Network:

```
ISP
 |    [wired]
Modem
 |    [wired]   |    [wired]
SSHServer    Router
                |    [wireless]
             Client
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have to configure your router to forward the port.

Comment: If it would be the same network it should be no problem ... are all devices configured to "know" the complete network ? so with netmask 255.255.25**4**.0?